# OSM create editable map to draw polyline path and markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I would like to use OSM to create a small project, but i face this map first time and not sure if it possible to create something i want with it.
As I figured out, there is nice library Leaflet to handle some simple operation with map.
But I want some extra features:

1) I need to draw polyline on map like paths on map. It should be editable or readonly.

2) I need to have controls to create markers with custom text in popup. It also should be editable or readonly.

3) I would like to have an option to customize style of lines and markers

4) I would like to collect some geo info or/and measurements based on markers and polyline paths.

Is it possible? Could you please provide me some info about want will be great for each of my points? I saw many plugins for Leaflet, but not sure is it helpful enough.
Thanks!

Comment: Both Leaflet and OpenLayers can be used to create markers, popups, polygons and more. Both have extensive documentation and various examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have more than one solution for your requirements- custom map style, custom pois: [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) offers an extensive bunch of features and  is probably the most widely used.
[Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) is simple to use, relatively intuitive.

Then, you can choose different layers-  popular commercial options (the free tier should be sufficient for most use cases):  [Skobbler‘s leaflet plugin](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/web)-allows you also to add overlays & other visual elements on top of the map, [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/), [MapQuest Open](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map)-free for any number of requests.